# moved at 120 kilometres an hour / was moving at 120 kilometres an hour

Tags: past-tense

> When I was stopped by the police, I **moved** at 120 kilometres an hour. {Past Simple expresses a fact of that speed}

> When I was stopped by the police, I **was moving** at 120 kilometres an hour. {Past Continious expresses some time of moving at that speed}

Is it possible to use both versions? As I understand it, there is nothing wrong to use Past Simple here.

Comment: ***When*** can mean ***at that time*** (and possibly before ad/or after that time), and that's the sense in your *second* example with the continuous verb. OR it can mean ***starting** from that time* - which in principle is the meaning associated with Simple Past in your first example. Except that doesn't make sense, so your example #1 is essentially "invalid".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Using the first version ("moved"/past simple) would be incorrect, because it implies that you *began to move* at that speed after you had been stopped. Compare:

> When I was hit by the baseball bat, I fell over.

This means that you fell over after being hit by the bat.

The second version ("was moving") is correct. Of course, there is some small inconsistency in the sentence: if you were *moving*, you were not *stopped*! But we understand "was stopped by the police" to mean the entire process: The police seeing you, turning on their lights, and making you slow down and pull over.

Answer (score 4):

The past tense form is not possible.

"When you were stopped" is the time of the event, and that contradicts "I moved at 120 km/h"  If you were stopped you can't move at all.  You could understand the first one as a narrative in chronological order, in which case the movement at 120 km/h must occur *after* the police (tried) to stop you.

That is not what you want to say!  The past continuous is strongly indicated here.  One event was ongoing at the time of another event (and in particular the ongoing event was a direct cause of other event)